# Django determine "most popular"

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

Given this somewhat simplified representation of my application's models, my question is *how do I globally find the most popular `MyModel`*? I.e., those `MyModel`s are favorited the most by `MyUser`s.

I've come across similar blog posts about how to find favorite *tags*, but I don't think those apply to this particular situation.

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
  favorite_models = models.ManyToManyField(MyModel)
  ...


class MyModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(...)
  ...
```

Can this be done in a single query? Or do I need to loop over every `MyUser` and `MyModel` to determine the most popular? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can surely do it in a query, as you would with sql.. I don't remember the exact syntax, though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm too lazy to create a django project from scratch, but this one should do the job:

```
from django.db.models import Count
MyModel.objects.annotate(Count('myuser'))
```

(or this)

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(Count('myuser_set'))
```

if not, try this:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    favorite_models = models.ManyToManyField(MyModel, related_name='myuser')
```

and then

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(Count('myuser_set'))
```

(let me know if it works, in any case this page should contain what you need to do that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)